# What's the best way to concat two integers for SQL Redshift?

Tags: sql, string, amazon-web-services, concatenation, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a simple key value that will look like 'subid_pid' where subid and pid are integers.
I tried doing concat(subid+'_'+pid) and I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong

Comment: You cannot concatenate two integers. [think: types]

Answer (score 4):

`+` is string arithmetic.  To concatenate strings, use the  `||` operator.  Redshift should convert numbers automatically.  So, you only need:

```
(subid || '_' || pid)
```

If you really want an explicit conversion, then `text` is convenient:

```
(subid::text || '_' || pid::text)
```

Comment: Thanks. (subid || '_' || pid) works but when I then go to run a count on these values, it's doing something fishy. The count is wrong.

Comment: @Lgdance . . . This answers the question that you have asked here, and that question has nothing to do with counting anything.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the integers to strings and concatenate them with `||`:

```
subid::varchar(20) || '_' || pid::varchar(20)
```

Comment: Is it best to do strings or text?

Comment: @Lgdance: both are OK here.

Comment: Merci beaucoup GMB https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb